# Route.put() required a call back function [object undefined] Request <computed>

Tags: node.js, express

it's properly installed. And I properly declared it in my express.js file so I'm unsure what I did wrong.

```
const express = require ("express");
    const Order = require("../Models/orderModel");
    const {isAuth, isAdmin, isAccount} = require("../util");
    
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.get("/", isAuth, async (req, res) =>{
        const orders = await Order.find({}).populate('user');
        res.send(orders)
    });
    
    app.get("/:id",isAuth, async(req, res) => {
        const order = await Order.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
      if (order) {
        res.send(order);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send("Order Not Found.")
      }
    } );
    
    app.get("/mine", isAuth, async (req, res) => {
        const orders = await Order.find({ user: req.user._id });
        res.send(orders);
      });
    
      
    app.delete("/:id", isAuth, isAdmin, isAccount,  async (req, res) => {
        const order = await Order.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
        if (order) {
          const deletedOrder = await order.remove();
          res.send(deletedOrder);
        } else {
          res.status(404).send("Order Not Found.")
        }
      });
    
      app.post("/", isAuth, async (req, res) => {
        const newOrder = new Order({
          orderItems: req.body.orderItems,
          user: req.user._id,
          shipping: req.body.shipping,
          payment: req.body.payment,
          itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice,
          taxPrice: req.body.taxPrice,
          shippingPrice: req.body.shippingPrice,
          totalPrice: req.body.totalPrice,
        });
    
        const newOrderCreated = await newOrder.save();
        res.status(201).send({ message: "New Order Created", data: newOrderCreated });
      });
      
      app.put("/:id/pay", isAuth, async (req, res) => {
        const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id);
        if (order) {
          order.isPaid = true;
          order.paidAt = Date.now();
          order.payment = {
            paymentMethod: 'paypal',
            paymentResult: {
              payerID: req.body.payerID,
              orderID: req.body.orderID,
              paymentID: req.body.paymentID
            }
          }
          const updatedOrder = await order.save();
          res.send({ message: 'Order Paid.', order: updatedOrder });
        } else {
          res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order not found.' })
        }
      });
```

My terminal console is giving me the following:

i am getting an error,  the route call function, not able to find the exact the solution for this error.. can anyone help me on this.
controller imported correctly, and also my controller action (the function) written in the same at api and cntroller

```
E:\Web Development\projsrc\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.put() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as put] (E:\Web Development\projsrc\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as put] (E:\Web Development\projsrc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web Development\projsrc\server\backend\Routes\userRoute.js:7:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web Development\projsrc\server\backend\server.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: Please share your code.
And copy paste the error instead of sharing a picture. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: i have pasted the code -Benard, can you please help me on this.

Comment: Can you share the `server\backend\Routes\userRoute.js:7:5` code please